# jest snapshot testing with redux set props of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, axios, jestjs

I am trying to render a snapshot of my component and have managed to test that my `componentDidMount` function is being called and my data is being set as the console.log inside my componentDidMount is showing this when running my test.

When my component loads up, because of the check for `this.props.data` in my `render()`, the component in my snapshot returns `null`. It then loads `componentDidMount` and sets the data which gets passed to the reducer to update the state.

I am trying to render a snapshot showing `<one/>`, `<two/>`, `<three/>`. Is there a way to directly set `this.props.data` in my situation so that I can bypass and not get into that "if" to render all my child components.

**App Component:**

```
 componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.data === null) {

        this.props.axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/123`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log("getting in here and res is :" + res) // {data: is showing}
                this.props.setData(res.data);
            })
    }
}



render() {
       if (this.props.data === null) {
            if (this.props.error) {
                console.log(this.props.error); 
            }
            return null;
        }

        return <div>
            <One oneData={this.props.data.one}/>
            <Two twoData={this.props.data.two}/>
            <Three threeData={this.props.data.three}/>
        </div>
}
```

In the same component I am dispatching to the reducer which updates the store:

```
dispatch => ({
    setData: data => dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA", dataPayload: data 
})
```

**Test file:**

```
import React from "react";
import App from "../../src/components/App";
import reducers from "../../src/reducers";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
const store = createStore(reducers);
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    get: jest.fn()
 }));
import {get} from "axios";
import axios from "axios";

it('renders correctly', async() => {
  const p = Promise.resolve({
       data: {
          "_id" : "123",
          "location" : "LONDON",
       }
  });

  const component = renderer.create(
      <Provider store={store}>
           <App axios={axios}/>
      </Provider>
  );

  console.log(store); 
  let tree = component.toJSON();

  await p;

  console.log("TREE :" + tree); // is returning null
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually pass props to `App`. See the example below:

```
  const data = {
    myProp: ...
  }

  const component = renderer.create(
    <App {...data} />
  );

  const tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Comment: Hi, I have managed to do that and can create other props but data always seems to be null

Answer (score 0):

1st, your resolved promise was not used with your mocked axios => no affect to your component

2nd, even if somehow you can return your resolved promise by your mock axios, you still not have what you want. This is because `renderer.create(...)` will not wait for your execution to do the 2nd rendering.

=> so with your current test => there is no way to get your requirement.

Solution:

Identify your Subject Under Test (SUT) and what behavior you want to test.

In this case, you want test rendering behavior of your component. This means your must get rid of other dependencies (and it is your life cycle methods). So simply:

```
App.componentDidMount = jest.fn(); // this is the way to replace real implementation with a mock
```

Then:

```
const mycomp = render.create(<App myProp={null} />); // this is the 1st case (null data)
expect(mycomp.toMatchSnapshot());

mycomp.update(<App myProp={data} />);
expect(mycomp.toMatchSnapshot()); // this is the 2nd case (has data)
```

Note: I don't know the structure of your props => so you must edit to fit your real code, above is just example.